# Provide context information across modules without passing parameters in loggers

Tags: python, logging, flask

i am implementing logging across a python web flask application. The below is an example structure

controller - com.org.python.MainController

has routes say /login, /doSomething, /logout

each of these routes call separate methods in separate modules say,

```
com.org.python.login.begin()
com.org.python.dosomething.execute()
com.org.python.logout.end()
```

my maincontroller routes have access to user id who has invoked the transaction and a unique transaction id which is generated. i can log this information easily using loggers.

usecase: i need to log user id and transaction id in the lower level modules as well , without passing the details as parameters

How can i achieve the same?

solution so far

```
 class CustomFilter(logger.Filter):


    def __init__(self, username, trid):
         self.username = username
         self.trid = trid

    def filter(record):
        record.username = self.username
        record.trid = self.trid
```

i have added the filter to logger as given above

maincontroller.py

```
def login(username):

    trid = ....
    log = logger.getLogger("something")
    log.addFilter(CustomFilter(username, trid))
    #handlers, formatters added as used
    log.info("inside login method")
    #import login module
    login.begin()
```

login.py

```
def begin():
    log = logger.getLogger("something")
    log.info("im inside begin method in login module")
    ### something something
```

the above works fine, username and trid is printed everywhere even across modules. **however the same trid and username is being used everywhere. even transactions not initiated by the same user. do we have to clear the filters? how can i achieve my usecase m the desired username and diff trid for diff transactions**

P.S: for some reason loggerAdaptors are not working. the info in adaptor is not getting transferred across module calls

please help.

Comment: You should explore [Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) library for python](https://pypi.org/project/mdc/),.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?